# How to start and rfid attendance using flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, rfid

I have created an attendance taking app for school where teacher manually submit student attendance to server. Now I want to create a flutter app which can read rfid card and take student attendance using mobile app and rfid card, but I am having trouble to start like how to pursue it and how to achieve it.

Comment: You can probably use this package to help you scan rfid: https://pub.dev/packages/zebra_rfid/

Answer (score 0):

To read RFID card in app your device must support NFC (Near Field Communication).

You can use this `flutter_nfc_reader` flutter plugin to read RFID cars in your flutter app. This plugin is supported in both iOS and Android.

Plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_reader

If the device doesn't support NFC, then you can use a microcontroller with an RFID module to read RFID cards and Bluetooth to communicate with the Flutter app.

1. You can choose [esp-32](https://www.amazon.in/Allianztec-ESP-WROOM-32-Development-Microcontroller-Integrated/dp/B08VJ2CKG1) which has inbuilt Bluetooth.
2. You can also choose Arduino [uno](https://robu.in/product/arduino-uno-r3/), [nano](https://robu.in/product/arduino-nano-v3-0-ch340-chip-mini-usb-cable/) with [hc-05](https://www.amazon.in/DIY-Retails-Bluetooth-Transceiver-Outputs/dp/B019OR9YVU/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=hc05+bluetooth+module&qid=1678857440&sprefix=hc05%2Caps%2C317&sr=8-3) or [hm-10](https://robu.in/product/at-09-bluetooth-4-0-uart-transceiver-module-cc2541-compatible-with-hm-10/) Bluetooth module.
3. You can use [this](https://robu.in/product/rc522-rfid-card-reader-module-13-56mhz/) RFID module to read RFID cards.

In flutter app you can choose these plugins to communicate with micro-controller through Bluetooth communication.

1. [flutter_bluetooth_serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial)  Note: if you are using HC-05 Bluetooth module or Esp-32
2. [flutter_blue_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus)  Note: if you are using HM-10 Bluetooth module

HC-05 is an Classic Bluetooth Module and HM-10 is Bluetooth Low Energy Module